# C#, microsoft bot

Tags: c#, botframework

I've created a simple chat bot using Microsoft QnA Maker cognitive service. Is there any parallel product available from any other vendor like facebook, google, IBM etc like QnA Maker service?

Comment: Please take a look at [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)! "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [api.ai](https://api.ai/) . I don't know about others but if you google it you should find a few easily.